# VBA.Find and adding a value

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to find a specific value in a column in an Excel sheet, and then add a value (=1) three columns to the right.

My code:

```
Sub AddNote()
    ActiveSheet.Range("F:F").Find(What:="Cat").Select
    Selection.Offset(0, 4).Value = 1
End Sub
```

Only I got:

> Error message 91: `Object variable or With block variable not set.

What is wrong with my commands?

Comment: You need to provide particulars as to what sort of `.Find` you are looking to perform; e.g. full or partial match, case sensitive or not, etc. Are you open to an alternative method that does not incorporate Find (e.g. [MATCH function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca))? Your description says *' three colums[sic] to the right'* but your code says 4 columns to the right.

Comment: By adding 1, do you mean adding 1 to the existing value?

Comment: Thank you for all helpful tips. What if I want to search ( .Find) value found in another cell.

I have two excel workbooks. In another I have some reports linked to a name. I have to find that name in another workbook and add value 1 to mark it as done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at this :

```
Sub test_IngaB()
Dim FirstAddress As String, cF As Range, LookForString As String
LookForString = "Cat"

With ThisWorkBook.Sheets("Sheet's name").Range("F:F")
    .Cells(1,1).Activate
    'First, define properly the Find method
    Set cF = .Find(What:=LookForString, _
                After:=ActiveCell, _
                LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                LookAt:=xlPart, _
                SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                MatchCase:=False, _
                SearchFormat:=False)

    'If there is a result, keep looking with FindNext method
    If Not cF Is Nothing Then
        FirstAddress = cF.Address
        Do
            cF.Offset(0, 3).Value = 1
            Set cF = .FindNext(cF)
        'Look until you find again the first result
        Loop While Not cF Is Nothing And cF.Address <> FirstAddress
    End If
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, this was very helpful. 
What if I want to search ( .Find) value found in another cell? I have two excel workbooks. In another I have some reports linked to a name. I have to find that name in another workbook and add value 1 to mark it as done.

Comment: This is not simply *very helpful*, this is one of the most elegant answers solving your issue (even taking into consideration that you didn't specify you wanted it to execute for each match). Feel free to accept this answer and then ask for the specifics in another one. To answer your brief question though: worksheets are subsets of the workbooks. Proper referencing would go like wb.ws.rng where rng is a range. You use the default: (ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.)Range instead.

Comment: _Not sure what you're asking there_, but you can run that code into the other workbook and just change what you are looking for (i.e. "Cat" there) **OR** you have to specify the workbook before `ActiveSheet.[...]`

Comment: The problem is that how do I add a value in some Cell to the method Find. What should I replace onto "cat"?

Comment: Got it working!

Sorry about changing the content of the original question.

Comment: Just change `Sub test_IngaB()` to `Sub test_IngaB(ByVal FindText as String)` and `Set cF = .Find(What:="Cat", _` to `Set cF = .Find(What:=FindText, _`
And you will use this `test_IngaB "Cat"` in your code

Answer (score 2):

> Error message 91: `Object variable or With block variable not set.

this error means that searching is failed, there is no "Cat" in column

try this:

```
Sub test()
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = ActiveSheet.[F:F].Find("Cat")
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        rng.Offset(, 4).Value = 1
    Else
        MsgBox "Searching criteria does not exists in column [F]!"
    End If
End Sub
```

and also one comment, avoid usage of the `select` and `selection` method, this is bad practice

Comment: FWIW allowing the runtime to raise an error that's easily avoided by not calling `.Offset` on a known possible null reference, is also bad practice.

Comment: @Mat'sMug thank you for your comments, noted, post has been updated

Answer (score 0):

If the `.Find` method doesn't output a range (there is no match for "Cat") then the `.Offset` method will halt into an error.

A structured solution would be along the lines of:

```
Sub AddNote()
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("F:F")
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(rng, "*Cat*") <> 0 Then 'if there is a match for "Cat" (LookAt:=xlPart), if you want exact matches, remove the asterisks
        rng.Find(What:="Cat").Select
        Selection.Offset(0, 4).Value = 1
    End If
End Sub
```