# Look for which cell in a row has a numberic value and return that value to another cell

Tags: vba, excel

I have a row that only one cell within that row will contain a number value (which could be any number).

On another sheet I need a formula which will find if the number from the row and return me that number value?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30161124/vba-find-and-adding-a-value/30162390#30162390) should be a good start, but you'll need to tune it yourself to fit your need. Try to improve it and edit your post to include your modified code so that you have worked on it before we help you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like that would give you the first number found in column A.

```
=INDEX(A:A,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISNUMBER(A:A),0),0))
```

It scans the column until it finds a number and writes it down in the cell.