# If (search term) found, do (action). If not, end if

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement, find

If you guys could help me out, that would be great because it would really help me.

Here's what I'm trying to do:

1. Search for a cell with a specific term
2. If found, copy the entire row that the cell is in and paste it into a row above it.
3. If not found, do nothing and continue with the code

Here's my code:

```
Sub Test()
'
' Test Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+b
'

    Range("A5").Select
    Cells.Find(What:="PL 1", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
        :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
        False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
    If Not IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Value) Then
        ActiveCell.Rows("1:1").EntireRow.Select
        Selection.Copy
        Range("A5").Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
    End If
    Range("A5").Select
    Cells.Find(What:="PL 2", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
        :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
        False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
    If Not IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Value) Then
        ActiveCell.Rows("1:1").EntireRow.Select
        Selection.Copy
        Range("A6").Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
    End If
    Range("A5").Select
    Cells.Find(What:="PL 3", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
        :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
        False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
    If Not IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Value) Then
        ActiveCell.Rows("1:1").EntireRow.Select
        Selection.Copy
        Range("A7").Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
    End If
End Sub
```

My code only works if the value is found. If it's not found it runs into the error below: [image]

Comment: "It's not working, obviously" You need to tell us what it's doing, over what specific data, and what you expect it to do. Not only are you asking for SO to debug this for you, you're asking for debugging to be done blindly, without even knowing what your source data looks like.

Comment: Also, this has been asked hundreds of times on SO. Good on you to write your own code but why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: @findwindow do you have a link? I can't find it.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon I appreciate your passion.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=search+string+copy+row

Comment: @findwindow Thanks for the link. I can actually search and copy just fine if my search term is found in the sheet. My problem is that my search term isn't always in my sheet and I need some way to pass over the search term and move on to the next one.

Comment: So add an `if`statement?

Comment: As you can see in my code, I attempted to do just what you suggested but I failed. That's why I'm asking for help.

Comment: Oh, just saw the edit XD

Comment: @GeorgeTye : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30161124/vba-find-and-adding-a-value/30162390#30162390 : Here is an example of the structure if you want to keep searching after doing your actions! ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Cells.Find` is a function that returns a `Range` object reference; when it doesn't find anything, the reference will be `Nothing`. And you can't call `.Activate` on `Nothing`:

> *This method returns Nothing if no match is found. The Find method does not affect the selection or the active cell.* ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx))

```
Cells.Find(What:="PL 2", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
    :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
    False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
```

You need to rewrite your code and **avoid .Select and .Activate**, and avoid working with `ActiveCell` and implicitly with `ActiveSheet` (which you are doing by not qualifying the `Cells` call with a proper worksheet reference).

Your formatting makes it hard to read the code, for several reasons:

- Arguments are being specified on different lines
- Line continuations are being palced at arbitrary locations
- Nested member calls aren't lined up

Compare to:

```
Cells.Find(What:="PL 2", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
           LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
           MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False) _
     .Activate
```

That's just readability. The problem is that you basically *assume* that `.Find` returns a valid object reference. **Don't assume, explicitly check:**

```
Set result = Cells.Find(...)
If Not result Is Nothing Then result.Activate
```

But really, you need to figure out a way to avoid .Select and .Activate.

Comment: Wow. Perfect answer. This is exactly what I was looking for. Now I understand where I was wrong much better.

Comment: So why are .Select and .Activate bad?

Comment: Because they make your code extremely brittle, harder to follow, and uselessly slow. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10714251/1188513) for *how* to avoid them, and [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa139976(v=office.10).aspx) as well as [this blog post](http://www.businessprogrammer.com/power-excel-vba-secret-avoid-using-select/) and [this Office blog entry about VBA best practices](https://blogs.office.com/2009/03/12/excel-vba-performance-coding-best-practices/), for the *why*.

Comment: Thanks so much Mat's Mug. Geez Mat must have been a really talented potter to come up with something (someone?) as helpful as you.

Comment: I wrote some code that is sufficient for what I need to do. Sure, it is a little slow but it's still 1000x faster than doing it manually. However, I will definitely read through the materials you suggested because I am always looking to improve.

Comment: Thanks! Feel free to come over to [codereview.se] with your working code looking for improvement =)

Comment: Oh wow. Stack Overflow has everything doesn't it? That sounds like a great idea. I actually made a project in Javascript that I would be interested in getting reviewed as well. I will definitely be headed there at some point in the future.

Answer (score 3):

You can try something like this instead (untested):

```
Sub HideAndSeek()

    Dim foundCell As Range

    For i = 1 To 3
        Set foundCell = Cells.Find(What:="PL " & i, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart)
        If Not foundCell Is Nothing Then
            Intersect(foundCell.EntireRow, ActiveSheet.UsedRange).Offset(-1, 0).Value = _
                Intersect(foundCell.EntireRow, ActiveSheet.UsedRange).Value
        End If
        Set foundCell = Nothing
    Next

End Sub
```

The principle being that you write the code you need *once* and then create a loop to repeat the code for you.

The other part of this answer is checking that the cell was found - to do this we check that the range was actually set (which means it isn't `Nothing`) using

```
If Not foundRange Is Nothing
```

Comment: Thanks for being so helpful @Macro Man! I'll try this. I think it might have been difficult for the other people to see what the issue was, so it helps to have someone like you.

Comment: I'm having a little trouble understanding your code. Why did you use Intersect()? What's the advantage of that over simple copy & paste?

Comment: `Intersect()` finds returns the section where 2 ranges overlap (or _intersect_). In general it's better to directly write the value of a range to another range rather than copy/paste (cleaner and less overhead). Rather than do that for the _entire_ row which is overkill I just used `Intersect` to find where the whole row and the used range overlap, and then write that value to the same area but one row above using `Offset(-1, 0)`

Comment: Oh ok thanks. What if I want it to write to a specific row? Is that possible?