# Overflow when using DateAdd Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, date

I currently have an Excel sheet with a series of dates and a cell in a different sheet with the date when we last ran this macro.

I need to write a macro which checks if today's date is at least 32 days after the day we last ran the macro.

If so, I want to search the sheet with the series of dates and add 10-dates to a dates array.

The dates that we add represent each the closes n*30 days prior to today's date with n which goes from 1 to 10.

So basically 10-dates each representing a multiple of 30-days prior to todays date.

BUT, these dates must be present in the sheet with the series of dates mentioned above so if for example subtracting 30 days from today gives a date which does not exist in the series of dates above, we keep subtracting 1 additional day until we find a date which exists.

Hope this makes sense. I understand it is a bit confusing but I felt I had to give some context.

My code:

```
Sub date_diff()
    Dim todDate
    Dim dt
    Dim diff As Long
    Dim dates(0 To 9) As Date
    Dim i As Long
    todDate = Format(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Overview").Range("B6").Value, "mm/dd/yyyy")
' dt is the Date of last signaling
    dt = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Overview").Range("B5").Value
    diff = DateDiff("d", dt, todDate)
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim dtCell As Range
    Dim currDt
    If diff < 32 Then
        MsgBox "Wait " & (32 - diff) & " days"
    Else
        For i = 1 To 10
           currDt = Format(DateAdd("d", 20, todDate), "mm/dd/yyyy") ---> OVERFLOW HERE
           Set rng = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("US Stocks").Range("A:A")
        ' Find the day - Loop until you find one at least 30 days apart
            Do While rng.Find(What:=currDt) Is Nothing
                currDt = DateAdd("d", -1, currDt)
            Loop
            dates(i) = currDt
            MsgBox i
        Next i
    End If
End Sub
```

> Run-time error '6':
>       Overflow

I suppose the error is coming from how I handle or how the dates are interpreted in VBA. SEE CODE FOR OVERFLOW LINE. I am very new to VBA so am still learning these subtleties. FYI, the dates are in the "Short Date" format such as 1/13/15 (mm/dd/yy).

Comment: this is infinite loop `Do While rng.Find(What:=currDt) Is Nothing`, you are    just searching the same range again and again. In the end any datattype will overflow.

Comment: See a proper use of `Range.Find` to use it in your code and loop on `FindNext`, not `Find`! ;) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30161124/vba-find-and-adding-a-value/30162390#30162390

Comment: @cyboashu My understanding is that rng.Find will return Nothing if it does not find currDt in the rng. If that is the case, we subtract 1-day from currDt and repeat the process until we find a currDt which exists in rng. Is my understanding incorrect?

Comment: @R3uK But, FindNext appears to be appropriate if for example you are searching for data which has duplicates within the range since Find only gets the first occurence. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx

Comment: I have added the line at which the overflow occurs and just to give more context, rng does not have any duplicate dates.

Comment: Using Find with dates is generally problematic, especially if they are the result of formulas. Try wrapping the date in a `CDbl()` call when searching for it. You could also use `Application.Match` or `Countif` instead.