# Create range from found cell to lastrow

Tags: vba, excel, find, range

I want to create a range from a cell containing, for example, the word "alex" to lastrow, in the first column.

Let's call this `cell-alex`.

The idea is to make:

```
range(cell-alex, cells(lastrow, 1)).
```

I know how to get lastrow, but not cell-alex. Excel always selects the range from A1 to the lastrow.

```vb
Cells.Find(What:="alex", after:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _
  xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=True _
  , SearchFormat:=True).Select        
Set sht = Worksheets(sheetbr)
lastrow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Range(ActiveCell, Cells(lastrow, 13)).Select
```

Answer (score 1):

if you know for sure that "Alex" is in column 1, then use this:

```
With Worksheets(sheetbr)
    .Range(.Columns(1).Find(What:="alex", after:=.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1), LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=True, _
                            SearchFormat:=True), _
           .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)).Select
End With
```

otherwise use this:

```
Dim f As Range

With Worksheets(sheetbr)
    Set f = .Columns(1).Find(What:="alex", after:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _
            xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=True _
            , SearchFormat:=True)
    If Not f Is Nothing Then .Range(f, .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)).Select
End With
```

Comment: @PeterPeanut, did you get through it?

Comment: It's working now. I don't know why, but somehow it WAS a problem with lastrow. I edited Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1). Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is LookIn:=xlFormulas. Try changing to LookIn:=xlValues

Answer (score 0):

All right, I have figured out this.
I did not tell you everything.
I start my code with importing another document.
While I was working on my code, the moment you mention ActiveCell it starts working with the other book.
I resolved it by copying data from my imported spreadsheet to the original (book1).
The rest was easy. Here it goes:

```
Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
lastrow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'to find the lastRow
Cells.Find(What:="GuV 7", after:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _
            xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
            , SearchFormat:=True).Activate
Range(ActiveCell, Cells(lastrow, 13)).Select 'I need columns 1-13
```

Once again, thanks guys.

Comment: **Please take the tour to see how SO works : http://stackoverflow.com/tour** and see this for a proper use of `.Find` method : http://stackoverflow.com/a/30162390/4628637