# VBA: Search mm's written text in the cell and copy

Tags: vba, excel, find

I've a workbook to define clearences between 2 parts.
I need to copy only mm's(dimension) with numbers to another workbook.

I tried it w/ recording macro but i couldn't find any solution.

[image: Excel Picture]

Comment: Take a minute to take the tour : http://stackoverflow.com/tour . What have you tried so far? You can look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30161124/vba-find-and-adding-a-value/30162390#30162390 to see how to use `Find` method and then you'll have to use Strings function to extract the data!

Answer (score 1):

you may try this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub main2()
    Dim destinationWS As Worksheet
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim clearances As Variant
    Dim iClearance As Long

    Set destinationWS = Workbooks("destinationWorkbookName").Worksheets("destinationWorksheetName") '<--| change "destinationWorkbookName" and "destinationWorksheetName" to your actual names

    With Range("C1", Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp))
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="*mm*"
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Cells) > 1 Then
            With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
                ReDim clearances(1 To .Count)
                For Each cell In .Cells
                    iClearance = iClearance + 1
                    clearances(iClearance) = GetClearance(cell.Value)
                Next cell
            End With
            destinationWS.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(clearances)).Value = Application.Transpose(clearances)
        End If
        .Parent.AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
End Sub

Function GetClearance(strng As String) As String
    Dim word As Variant

    For Each word In Split(strng, " ")
        If InStr(word, "mm") > 0 Then
            GetClearance = word
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

Comment: @AliYasinÖZ, did you get through it?

Answer (score 1):

When i run the macro i got the Picture below :(

Can we put the clearances to D column on the same part row?

Picture *---->*[Macro result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sbj4f.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I solve my problem myself. This title can be closed.

Thanks

```
Sub aaa()
    Set Rky = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    Rky.Pattern = "\w*([0-9])" & "mm"
    For i = 1 To Range("A65536").End(3).Row
      If Cells(i, "a").Value Like "*mm*" Then
        Cells(i, "C") = Rky.Execute(Cells(i, "A")).Item(0)
      End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Fine. And sorry I annoyed you with my solution. Would you have me to delete it?