# VBA check criteria in 1 workbook, input values in another workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I am struggling to figure out how to get the code to do what I want, I wrote as much as I could with what I could find online, but for some aspects, I don't know what write.

**Purpose of the code**

Check "spreadsheet 2017" for the number "1" next to each name. If there is a "1", then enter values in multiple cells in a row in another workbook called "Dates template" (in the same row as name in "spreadsheet 2017")

**Details on what I would like it to do**

1. Column A and B has list first name (A), and surname (B)
2. Check through column C for "1", next to the names
3. If there is a 1, then switch to workbook "Dates Template"
4. find the same name in column A, and put the values 7.2 (col B), 3.9 (col C) and 74.2 (col D).

This is the basic backbone of the code, in the future I will be looking to add additional conditions, such as 1 in column D for example as well 1 in column C. so maybe a case function would work better, then it would be easier to add in the future. I don't know which is better.

In the code below I only wrote it to scan through the surnames in column B, because there are no duplicates. but in the future, it is likely that there will be names with the same surname, in which case first name will have to be read as well. This is where I'm confused on how to check both.

A bonus would be if its possible to copy the list of names over to the "Dates template" and then input those values if the criteria is met. Because at the moment I manually type up the names onto the "Date Template" Spreadsheet.

```
Sub Summary()

    Dim wb1 As Workbook
    Dim Sht As Worksheet
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim wb2 As Workbook
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set wb1 = Workbooks("Works template.xlsm")
    Set wb2 = Workbooks("Spreadsheet 2017")
    Set Sht = wb1.Worksheets("Template") 
    Set ws = wb2.Worksheets("January")
    Set Rng = ws.Range("B7:B" & Sht.Cells(Sht.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row)

    For Each cell In Rng
        If cell.Offset(0, 2).Value = "1" Then
            Sht.Cells.Offset(0, 3).Value = "7.2" '<--- This is where I get the new error, "Application-defined or object-defined error"
            Sht.Cells.Offset(0, 2).Value = "3.9"
            Sht.Cells.Offset(0, 6).Value = "74.2"
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: It means that `"Works template.xlsx"` was not found. So it could be because it is not opened or because it is open in another instance of Excel! So was it opened when you try this?

Comment: Thank you, it was supposed to be xlsm at the end, I don't know how I missed that. But, now I'm getting "Application-defined or object-defined error" for the line Sht.Cells.Offset(0,3).Value = "7.2"

Comment: Some of Excels errors aren't as descriptive by themselves as they should be. In cases like these, you should start by running your code in single-step mode (default key: F8) and tracking the variables your using (wb1, wb2, Sht, ws, Rng). 

Do they all have an assigned value at their time of use? Is that value plausible? Are you assigning them a value that does not fit?

It's hard to debug this if we just have your code seeing as there could be a thousand things wrong with whatever your code reads in your workbooks.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I will have a go at what you suggested to find the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Sht.Cells` refers to all cells in the sheet, so you can't use `.Offset()` on this.

```
Sub Summary()

    Dim wb1 As Workbook
    Dim Sht As Worksheet
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim wb2 As Workbook
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set wb1 = Workbooks("Works template.xlsm")
    Set wb2 = Workbooks("Spreadsheet 2017")
    Set Sht = wb1.Worksheets("Template") 
    Set ws = wb2.Worksheets("January")
    Set Rng = ws.Range("B7:B" & Sht.Cells(Sht.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row)

    For Each cell In Rng
        If cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "1" Then
            sht.Range(cell.address).Offset(-2, 0).Offset(0, 0).Value = "7.2"
            sht.Range(cell.address).Offset(-2, 0).Offset(0, 1).Value = "3.9"
            sht.Range(cell.address).Offset(-2, 0).Offset(0, 2).Value = "74.2"
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, I will give that a go, but wouldn't this input the value in the same sheet? the values should be inputted in workbook "works template", whereas the 1 is in workbook "spreadsheet 2017"

Comment: @kira123 : Mkay, I missed some parts indeed! Is the name on the same row in `Workbooks("Works template.xlsm").Worksheets("Template")`?

Comment: the names are identical and in the same order, but start on a different row. In "works template" the list of names start on row 5, whereas in the the "spreadsheet 2017" it starts on row 7

Comment: @kira123 : So a -2 rows, would be enough! :) Let me a sec to update! ;)

Comment: Your amazing!! thank you once again!! Does this mean that the list of name on "works template" doesn't have to identical anymore?

Comment: @kira123 : Nope, at the moment, this work only because your lists are identical with just an offset(), if they are not, you'll have to use the `Find` method (see : http://stackoverflow.com/a/30162390/4628637)  and replace `sht.Range(cell.address).Offset(-2, 0).Offset(0, 0)` by `cF.Offset(0,1)` in the `Do` loop ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
 Sub Insertdata()
    Dim iAge As Integer
    Set src = Workbooks.Open("age.xlsm", True, True)
    t = 2
    lastrow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    Do Until t = lastrow
        iAge = src.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & t).Value
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & t).Value = iAge
        t = t + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

the same program how do we return not listing but connnected date with key
[How do we remake the program to copy one value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67296063/how-do-we-remake-the-program-to-copy-one-value?noredirect=1#comment118957573_67296063)