# VBA Code in Excel to select a cell based on two criteria

Tags: vba, excel, loops, find

What I want to happen is for a button to be pressed on "PP1 & PP2 Shortage list".

When this button is pressed I want the macro to take the values from D5 and F5 and locate the row where these two values appear in separate columns on "PP1 Paint plan".

It will then highlight columns A:AF below the found row copy everything and paste this back in to A2.

I have tried a number of loop codes and find codes but so far I have had no luck, I'm hoping one of you brilliant people could shed some fresh thinking on the problem.

Comment: Please show us what you've tried, you won't have answers like this... See an example here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/30162390/4628637

Comment: See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to frame a question to receive effective answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

R3uk is right but as you're looking for fresh ideas.

Why not combine a formula that can find the row number on "PP1 Paint plan" that matches your criteria with a simple macro that uses that row number to copy everything below. no looping required!

Put the formula below into an empty cell on the same sheet as you D5 and F5 cells.  I've used A1 in the macro.  Change the search columns accoridingly (I used $D:$D and $F:$F). IMPORTANT: press SHIFT+CTRL+ENTER to add {} to this formula.

=MATCH(D5&F5,'PP1 Paint plan'!$D:$D&'PP1 Paint plan'!$F:$F,0)

Next copy this code and change it as required.  It sets a variable called intFoundRow to the cell that contains the formula (change the A1 to your cell reference).  It then copies everything below that row and pastes it into your destination sheet.  I'm not sure what that is called so please change the text.

```
Sub CopyShortageData()
  intFoundRow = Sheets("PP1 & PP2 Shortage list").Range("A1").Value
  Range(Sheets("PP1 Paint plan").Range("A" & intFoundRow & ":AF" & intFoundRow), Sheets("PP1 Paint plan").Range("A" & intFoundRow & ":AF" & intFoundRow).End(xlDown)).Copy
  Sheets("Your destination sheet").Range("A2").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon, I am getting a Run time error 1004. On this line of code                                                                                                     Sheets("PP1 Paint plan").Range("A" & intFoundRow & ":AF" & intFoundRow).Select

Comment: Hi, sorry, I hadn't tested the code and it doesn't lke the "select" statements so I have changed the code and tested that it works.

Comment: Gordon you are a star!
Work perfectly in module but never worked when clicking activeX button. However that has now been solved by coding this on the buttons themselves:
 Module2.CopyShortageDataPP1

Anyway much appreciated and regards.
Joe