# VBA get values from 2 workbooks where value matches?

Tags: vba, excel

**Scenario**

I have three workbooks

```
Master
Planner
Phonebook
```

In my master workbook, i have a value in cell I8 on sheet 1.

Master (Sheet 1)

```
I8 = 2
```

On sheet 2 i have the following empty columns:

Master (Sheet 2)

```
Column A (number)      Column B (Supplier)     Column C (Contact)
```

I intend to populate these columns with data from both planner workbook and phonebook workbook.

In my planner, I have a list of numbers in column A and suppliers in Column N.

```
Numbers     Supplier    
2           A
2           B
2           C
3           D
4           E
2           F
```

I am trying to copy all the suppliers from my planner workbook that match the value in cell I8 (in this instance it is 2).

I am pasting the numbers (2) in column A and pasting the supplier names into column B in master workbook.

My code already copies and pastes these values fine.
(I am also copying other values from planner into other columns in master - but for this question, these are not relevant).

So this part of my code works fine.

**The problem**

Once the suppliers have been pasted into column B in master workbook - I also want to copy the contact name for each supplier from my workbook phonebook.

My phonebook workbook has sheets A-Z and suppliers are listed under these sheets alphabetically.

Phonebook:

```
    Supplier (Column A)       Contact Name (Column C)

    A                            Linda
    Aa                           Dave
    Aa                           Terry
    AB                           James

A | B | C | D etc...    <----- Sheets
```

I need to look in each sheet in column A of the phonebook for a supplier name that matches the supplier name in column B (master).

If the supplier name matches then I want to copy the contact name in column C over to master workbook column C.

My result should look like this

Master (Sheet 2)

```
Column A (number)      Column B (Supplier)     Column C (Contact)
2                      A                       Linda
2                      A                       Linda
```

Here's my code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub CreateAnnounce()

Dim WB As Workbook
Dim WB2 As Workbook
Dim i As Long
Dim i2 As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim j2 As Long
Dim LastRow2 As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet

'Open Planner
On Error Resume Next
Set WB = Workbooks("2017 Planner.xlsx")
On Error GoTo 0
If WB Is Nothing Then 'open workbook if not open
    Set WB = Workbooks.Open("G:\BUYING\Food Specials\2. Planning\1. Planning\1. Planner\8. 2017\2017 Planner.xlsx")
End If

'Open PhoneBook
On Error Resume Next
Set WB2 = Workbooks("Phone Book for Food Specials.xls")
On Error GoTo 0
If WB2 Is Nothing Then 'open workbook if not open
    Set WB2 = Workbooks.Open("G:\BUYING\Food Specials\1. General\Phone Book\Phone Book for Food Specials.xls")
End If

' ======= Edit #2 , also for DEBUG ======
With WB.Worksheets(1)
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    j = 2

    For i = 1 To LastRow


        ' === For DEBUG ONLY ===
        Debug.Print CInt(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("I8").Value)


        If CInt(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("I8").Value) = .Range("A" & i).Value Then ' check if Week No equals the value in "A1"

                ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Range("A" & j).Value = .Range("A" & i).Value
                ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Range("B" & j).Value = .Range("N" & i).Value
                ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Range("H" & j).Value = .Range("K" & i).Value
                ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Range("I" & j).Value = .Range("L" & i).Value

                ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Range("J" & j).Value = .Range("M" & i).Value
                ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Range("K" & j).Value = .Range("G" & i).Value

                ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Range("L" & j).Value = .Range("O" & i).Value
                ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Range("M" & j).Value = .Range("P" & i).Value

                ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Range("N" & j).Value = .Range("W" & i).Value
                ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Range("O" & j).Value = .Range("Z" & i).Value



                'Retrieve Contact Details for supplier

                'Worksheet 1



              'Retrieve Contact Details for supplier
             With WB2.Worksheets(2)
            LastRow2 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            j2 = 2

            For i2 = 1 To LastRow2
            Dim rngToFill As Range
            Set rngToFill = .Range("C2")

            Do

            Debug.Print ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Range("B" & j2).Value

            If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Range("B" & j2).Value Like .Range("A" & i2).Value Then ' check if Company equals the value in "B1 Phonebook"

            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Range("C2").Value = .Range("C" & i2).Value

            Set rngToFill = rngToFill.Offset(1, 0)


            End If

            Loop

            Next i2
            End With










           'Retrieve Contact Details for supplier - END




            End If

    Next i
End With


End Sub
```

For some reason, the code is Copying/pasting just 1 single contact name on the first row into master workbook.

I am also aware that at the moment I am only looking across one sheet.

```
With WB2.Worksheets(2)
```

I need this code to obviously look across all sheets for all supplier contact names.

Please can someone show me where I am going wrong and how to get this code to work? Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

I have composed the code suggested by user @BjornBogers

'Retrieve Contact Details for supplier

```
            Dim FoundCellRng As Range
            Dim ContactValue As String
            Dim SearchStr As String

            For i2 = 1 To 26
                'Assuming --> ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Range("B1").Value is what you are looking for?
                SearchStr = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Range("B2").Value
                Set FoundCellRng = WB2.Worksheets(i2).Range("A2:A200").Find(SearchStr)
                If (FoundCellRng Is Nothing) Then
                    'Didn't find anything
                Else
                    'We found it
                    ContactValue = WB2.Worksheets(i2).Cells(FoundCellRng.Row, FoundCellRng.Column + 2).Value
                    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Range("C" & j).Value = ContactValue
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next i2


           'Retrieve Contact Details for supplier - END
```

However, this does the same thing, only one contact name is being entered in the top row but nothing more.

EDIT 2:

With the code @R3uK provided, i seem to be getting the following issues:

[image]

Supplier names and other values are not copying across correctly.
The same value seems to repeat itself again and again in column I.

For some reason, this code creates another sheet? What is this sheet for?

[image]

The code is incredibly slow and i am having to wait 20 minutes or more.
Is there a way to speed this up?

Comment: Why don't you loop through the sheets and execute a find statement everytime? -> For i = 1 To 26  WB2.Worksheets(i).Range(A1:A100).Find(Value).Offset(, 2).Value Next i.
You have to check if it found something ofcourse but that would do the trick right?

Comment: @BjörnBogers possibly but i'm not to confident on how i would do this?

Comment: Just a suggestion: don't loop through the sheets. Take the first letter from the name of the supplier. It must match exactly one sheetname in phonebook. Just have to select the specific sheet. And so it's about 26 times (?) faster than looping through the sheets every time.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this but you could try the following:

```
                Dim FoundCellRng As Range
                Dim ContactValue As String
                Dim SearchStr As String

                For i = 1 To 26
                    'Assuming --> ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Range("B1").Value is what you are looking for?
                    SearchStr = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Range("B1").Value
                    Set FoundCellRng = WB2.Worksheets(i).Range("A1:A100").Find(SearchStr)
                    If (FoundCellRng Is Nothing) Then
                        'Didn't find anything
                    Else
                        'We found it
                        ContactValue = WB.Worksheets(i).Cells(FoundCellRng.Row, FoundCellRng.Column + 2).Value
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next i
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but  i get an error (subscript out of range) on this line: ContactValue = WB.Worksheets(i2).Cells(FoundCellRng.Row, FoundCellRng.Column + 2).Value

Comment: ok i fixed the error, It was WB instead of WB2. However, this doesn't seem to work either. See Edit. Same thing happens. Only 1 contact name is entered in the top row

Comment: You are missing a loop after you found the 1st result with `Find`, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30161124/vba-find-and-adding-a-value/30162390#30162390 for the use of `FindNext`! ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub CreateAnnounce()
Dim WbMaster As Workbook
Dim wSMaster1 As Worksheet
Dim wSMaster2 As Worksheet
Dim wSMastTemp As Worksheet
Dim WbPlan As Workbook
Dim wSPlan1 As Worksheet
Dim WbPhone As Workbook
Dim wSPhone As Worksheet
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim rngToFill As Range
Dim rngToChk As Range


Set WbMaster = ThisWorkbook
Set wSMaster1 = WbMaster.Sheets(1)
Set wSMaster2 = WbMaster.Sheets(2)
Set wSMastTemp = WbMaster.Sheets.Add
'''Open Planner
Set WbPlan = GetWB("2017 Planner.xlsx", "G:\BUYING\Food Specials\2. Planning\1. Planning\1. Planner\8. 2017\2017 Planner.xlsx")
Set wSPlan1 = WbPlan.Sheets(1)
'''Open PhoneBook
Set WbPhone = GetWB("Phone Book for Food Specials.xls", "G:\BUYING\Food Specials\1. General\Phone Book\Phone Book for Food Specials.xls")

With wSPlan1
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    j = 2
    For i = 1 To LastRow
        '''Check if Week No equals the value in "A1"
        If CInt(wSMaster1.Range("I8").Value) = .Range("A" & i).Value Then
            wSMaster2.Range("A" & j).Value = .Range("A" & i).Value
            wSMaster2.Range("B" & j).Value = .Range("N" & i).Value
            wSMaster2.Range("H" & j & ":J" & j).Value = .Range("K" & i & ":M" & i).Value
            wSMaster2.Range("K" & j).Value = .Range("G" & i).Value
            wSMaster2.Range("L" & j & ":M" & j).Value = .Range("O" & i & ":P" & i).Value
            wSMaster2.Range("N" & j).Value = .Range("W" & i).Value
            wSMaster2.Range("O" & j).Value = .Range("Z" & i).Value
            '''Store those infos for next results
            wSMastTemp.Cells.Clear
            wSMastTemp.Range("A1:O1").Value = wSMaster2.Range("A" & j & ":O" & j).Value

            '''Retrieve Contact Details for supplier
            Set rngToFill = wSMaster2.Range("C" & j)
            For Each wSPhone In WbPhone.Sheets
                With wSPhone
                    '''Define properly the Find method to find all
                    Set rngToChk = .Columns(1).Find(What:=wSMaster2.Range("B" & j).Value, _
                                After:=.Cells(1, 1), _
                                LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                                MatchCase:=False, _
                                SearchFormat:=False)

                    '''If there is a result, keep looking with FindNext method
                    If Not rngToChk Is Nothing Then
                        FirstAddress = rngToChk.Address
                        Do
                            '''Transfer the cell value to the master
                            rngToFill.Value = rngToChk.Offset(, 2).Value

                            '''Go to next row on the template for next Transfer
                            Set rngToFill = rngToFill.Offset(1, 0)
                            '''Copy the Info from 1st row for the next result
                            wSMaster2.Range("A" & rngToFill.Row & ":O" & rngToFill.Row).Value = wSMastTemp.Range("A1:O1").Value

                            '''Look until you find again the first result in that sheet
                            Set rngToChk = .Columns(1).FindNext(rngToChk)
                        Loop While Not rngToChk Is Nothing And rngToChk.Address <> FirstAddress
                    Else
                    End If
                End With 'wSPhone
          Next wSPhone
          '''Restart to fill from the next available row
          j = rngToFill.Row
          '''Clean Data that was there for the next result of this test
          wSMaster2.Range("A" & j & ":O" & j).ClearContents
        End If
    Next i
End With

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
wSMastTemp.Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub


Public Function GetWB(FileName As String, FileFullPath As String) As Workbook
    On Error Resume Next
    Set GetWB = Workbooks(FileName)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If GetWB Is Nothing Then 'open workbook if not open
        Set GetWB = Workbooks.Open(FilePath)
        DoEvents
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: thanks but i get an error, method or data member not found on this line: Set rngToChk = .FindNext(rngToChk)

Comment: @user7415328 : Corrected! ;) I forgot to report `.Columns(1)` before it! ;)

Comment: Thanks again, but see Edit 2. This code doesn't seem to do what is required.

Comment: @user7415328 : Are you suppliers in the Sheet corresponding to the 1st letter of their name in PhoneBook? How many rows is there in Planner?

Comment: possibly not, most the correspond however the spelling may be ever so slightly different for some. For instance 'supplier A' could be 'Supplier-A'. Could this be changed to 'value Like value'?

Comment: @user7415328 : Nope... That `-` will return a False with Like... You could define a set of rules to compare both in a custom function returning a boolean... One of them could be `Lcase(Replace(SuppName," ","-"))=OtherSuppName`.

Comment: i'm not sure that would work, since the supplier name might not just be seperated with - but . or ' or SupplierAs SupplierAS or Supplier As etc

Comment: @user7415328 : Look at the LCase function, and for the different characters, you could do multiple tests that's not an issue. As for the perf of the code, if you have a lot of rows and that the suppliers aren't a bit sorted in the phonebook, it'll take long for sure!

Comment: how comes this code is so slow? it takes forever and crashes excel most of the time :(